# How to Cast IList<IList<Object>> to list of specific type in F#

Tags: f#

I'm having some issues finding out how to cast a string array to a specific type.
Here is my code

```
type plItem = {
    sku: string
    name: string
    size: string
    buy: decimal
    sell: decimal
    barcode: string
}
// ....  ( get values from google sheets ) 
let values:IList<IList<Object>> = response.Values
let pl = values |> Seq.map ( fun item -> Seq.toArray )
```

[image]

At the end of the code - pl is now an array of strings.  I want to make it an aray of the type ( above ) plItem I'm not sure of the easiest way to to this.

Comment: What you may be looking for is a downcast: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions#downcasting

Comment: @PhillipCarter Thanks - but I tried and got the error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error FS0016 The type ''a -> 'b[]' does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source of a type test or runtime coercion.

Comment: @PhillipCarter  tried let pl = values |> Seq.map ( fun item -> Seq.toArray :?> plItem )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a list of list where the outer list represents rows and the nested list represents columns. You want to turn the rows into records and the columns correspond to individual record fields.

There is no automatic way of doing that. You'll just have to extract individual columns and convert them to an appropriate type (either by unboxing the type into a `string` or by getting the string value and then parsing it). Something like this:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type plItem = {
  sku: string
  name: string
  size: string
  buy: decimal
  sell: decimal
  barcode: string
}

let values:IList<IList<Object>> = 
  [| [| box "12660"; box "Probiotics 14 Strains"; box "60 VCaps"; 
        box "31.46"; box "50.35"; box "9403067126606"; |] :> IList<_> 
  |] :> IList<_>

let pl = values |> Seq.map (fun row -> 
  { sku = unbox row.[0]
    name = unbox row.[1]
    size = unbox row.[2]
    buy = decimal (unbox<string> row.[3])
    sell = decimal (unbox<string> row.[4])
    barcode = unbox row.[5] })
```